# Plotting density of various continuous variables in different subplots

Tags: python, plot

I want to plot density of various variables in different subplots but I receive it in one plot with the code below. What should be changed in order to solve it?

```
for var in continuous:
    cars[var].plot.kde()
```

Sample data:

```
displacement    horsepower  weight  acceleration
0   307.0   130.0   3504.0  12.0
1   350.0   165.0   3693.0  11.5
2   318.0   150.0   3436.0  11.0
3   304.0   150.0   3433.0  12.0
4   302.0   140.0   3449.0  10.5
```

And here is an example of presentation desired:
https://gyazo.com/c4a2e4cd62dbc480e32131a584e1eb0d

Comment: Could you please add sample data to the question, as well as an example of what *exactly* it is you're looking for? If could be a drawing on the back of a napkin.

Comment: @Roy2012 the info has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do this as subplots:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

for loc, col in zip(itertools.product([0,1], [0,1]), df.columns):
    df[col].plot.kde(ax = axs.item(*loc), title = col)
```

The output is:

[image]